# Looking for a C++ library to automate application updates

Tags: c++, windows

I have created a program in C++ but I want that the program download and install an update every month automatically and invisibly to the user. How can I do that ?

Comment: Perhaps the title was. I edited it to be more specific.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [Omaha](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/) from Google. They use it for most of their own products like Chrome.

Comment: +1 Cool!  I've never heard of this before.  Thanks for posting it!